# Python's print function does not show values sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found that Python's `print` function does not show values sequentially if some values are actually functions that also have `print` functions themselves, as in:

```py
def f():
    print("function called")

print('hello',f()) 
# function called
# hello None
```

I'm really confused why the print function will go to `f()` first before printing 'hello'. My expected output is

```
hello function called
None
```

My thinking is `print()` will first prints 'hello', then it will execute `f()`.

Could someone help with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: How is the `print` function supposed to know that your print function also has a print statement in it?

Comment: according to call stack, f() function will be resolved first then print function will be called finally so this output makes sense.

Comment: This is *how all functions work*. Areguments are *fully evalauted* before being passed into the function. IOW, `f()` is *called first*, and the result is passed to `print`. `"hello"` *is evaluated first*, but that doesn't cause anything to be printed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you so much! I overlooked the fact that `print` is also a function. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the parameter `f()` is evaluated first, before the `print()` is executed.

Comment: Yes I discovered it from the output, but I still can't see the reason why `print()` would do it this way? Also, if `f()` is evaulated first, then why the return value (None here) will be shown at the end? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Probabilityiswonderful this is *how it always works*.